# Drawing a point on a Label that is on top of a canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Label (there is an image) is located on the canvas throughout the volume. How can I put dots on top of label (they are apparently placed on canvas, but the image overlaps them. For example, I gave the interface of my program and circled the right place[image]

Please help me, I've been sitting with this problem for a long time, I can't get away from Label I need to use it. I also get the coordinates of the points from the picture, but you can't draw on the label

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk


class interface:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.panelA = None
        self.f1 = tk.Frame(self.root,)
        self.f1.grid()
        self.canvas2 = tk.Canvas(self.f1, height=610, width=1050,)
        self.canvas2.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def select_image(self):
        image = Image.open("Graf/Ag8.png")
        resize_image = image.resize((1050, 610))
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_image)
        self.panelA = tk.Label(self.f1, image=image)
        self.panelA.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)
        self.panelA.image = image
        self.panelA.grid(row=0, column=0)


    def callback(self, event):
        print(event.x, event.y)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    obj_interface = interface(root)
    obj_interface.select_image()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is that graphic just a hard-coded image embedded in your GUI? Or is it generated from data at runtime? If generated, by what library, and can your provide a [mre]?

Comment: @starball I added the code, shortened it as best I could. Can somehow do without Label. In addition to the coordinates, from the mouse click I need red dots from the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Label (there is an image) is located on the canvas throughout the volume. How can I put dots on top of label

You cannot draw on top of widgets embedded in a canvas. If you're using a `Label` just to embed an image, you can instead create an image object using the canvas method `create_image`. You can then draw items on top of the image.